# Cleaning up spilled loctite thread locking compound

Tags: tools, cleaning, threadlocker

I spilled locktite red 271 in my toolbox drawer.  It's dried and is covering the plastic tray as well as some of the tools.  Is there anything that will dissolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to dissolve it with anything which isn't going to ruin the toolbox if it's plastic. That you'll have to scrape out or just leave alone.

As for the tools, if they are metal, you can heat them up to kill the Loctite. That's how you'd get it to release if it was holding a bolt in place, so that's what you're going to have to do to get it off of them. I'd use a heat gun and use just enough to get it off and nothing more. You might be able to knock it off using a wire wheel, but I think you'd have less success with that until it is heated.

Other than that, it's pretty much just elbow grease. Chemicals are not going to cut it without causing other issues, so there you go.

Comment: Where can I buy elbow grease? ;)

Comment: @GdD same place I get it :)

Comment: @GdD - I usually find it at the parts store next to the muffler bearings ... :o)

Answer (score 0):

Acetone will soften thread locker compounds and can be used to remove it from bolts, nuts, threaded holes, and most tools.

But for a plastic toolbox tray you'll want to check on a small area first.  Some plastics are quickly softened by Acetone while others are quite resistant.